# How to base64 encode an object containing base64_encoded strings

Tags: php, base64

OK having trouble finding exactly what I'm trying to do here.

I am trying to base64_encode an object (called $email) which contains a property storing the HTML of the email ($email->body) which sometimes contains a base64_encoded inline image.

This is being returned via Ajax.

Everything returns fine if there is no inline image found in the HTML property. But if there is, the base64 strings seems to be colliding and the HTML compiling is ending early resulting in the return object missing pieces.

Everything in the HTML property is wrapped in a div with attributes.

EG

```
   <div id="email_'.$email->id.'" class="email-full-wrapper hide" data-email-info=\''.base64_encode(json_encode($email)).'\'>
       [ Other stuff goes here ]
     </div>
```

When a base64 image is found in $email->body, the encoding exits early and then [ Other stuff goes here ] never executes.

What do I need to do to make sure this doesn't happen?

Comment: I would suggest that transferring a serialised PHP object via AJAX is a bad idea. Perhaps you could encode the necessary data points from it in JSON and use that?

Comment: It's still going to happen when viewing an email which contains a base64 data image. So I need to figure it out either way